# Retrieving all active variables from all stackframes during an exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to figure out all active variables in all 'called' stack frames during an exception.

For example, consider the below example to illustrate the scenario

```
import time

def mainFunc():
    now = time.time()
    author = "me"
    callClient()

def callClient():
    message = "Hello, World!"
    to = "stackoverflow.com"
    callNoOp()
    callException()

def callNoOp():
    subject = "Question in stack trace"
    print "No-op"

def callException():
    question = "What do I do?"
    raise Exception("Vishwanathan, vellai vendum!")

mainFunc()
```

The exception is percolated up to `callClient`. I want to have a look at all active variables at that point. `locals()` would help me that requirement.

What I also want to know is the value of `message` and `to` at `callException()`. And the value of `question` when the exception is raised.

I have gone through the [`traceback` module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#module-traceback). It seems to print the stack trace but not the variables active in those stackframes.

Comment: Why are you calling a function to raise an exception? If you raised it from `callClient`, you would be able to include `to` and `message` in the traceback easily. Could you provide a less abstract example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to illustrate the scenario I am facing recently. Recently inherited a code with no documentation which was failing in multiple places. I do not have the mandate to make large changes in the code lest it becomes unstable during this high-traffic season. I rely only on the logs. I want to populate the logs with more data which can aid me in my debugging. Jon, would you consider removing the down-vote?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: to produce a sample traceback, probably.

Comment: @Sriram: which is exactly what tools like Zope and Django do; Zope even looks for explicit `__traceback_info__` locals to augment the logged information for exceptions.

Comment: I hope this request of having an even more data-filled stacktrace output can be accomodated in the `traceback` library some time in the future. Do you know where do I record this request of mine?

Comment: I see http://bugs.python.org/issue22936 requesting something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to find a workaround for the time being and it looks like this.

```
def mainFunc():
    now = time.time()
    author = "me"
    try:
        callClient()
    except:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        while tb:
            print tb.tb_lineno, "@", tb.tb_frame.f_locals
            tb = tb.tb_next
```

Answer (score 2):

The traceback consists of a chain of object, linked together through the `tb_next` attribute. Each traceback object also links to the frame through `tb_frame`, and each frame has a `f_locals` attribute.

Given a traceback object, you can print all locals along the chain with:

```
current = traceback
while current is not None:
    print current.tb_frame.f_locals
    current = current.tb_next
```

See the [*Standard type hierarchy* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) of the Python Datamodel (scroll down to *Traceback objects*).

You could also take a look at the [`inspect.trace()` utility function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.trace), which unpacks the chain into a sequence of named tuples:

```
import inspect

for frame_info in inspect.trace():
    print frame_info[0].f_locals
```

Do make sure you clear any references to the traceback explicitly; because a traceback includes a reference to the current namespace, it is almost trivial to create a circular reference here. At best that'll delay clearing those references, in the worst case an object with a `__del__` method is involved in the circle and then garbage collection will never break that circle and you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn. I was shooting arrows in the dark was able to come with something which resembles your solution (& I have posted my finding below too). I am going to upvote your answer.